# Worse performance when accessing common resource from within ddf.map_partitions call

Tags: pandas, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

I do encounter a performance issue, when accessing a global .nc file from within a dask.dataframe.map_partitions function.

**Some background:**
I have a large set of netCDF files with values being mapped to lat+lon values. For each val+lat+lon row, I want to calculate a distance to coast value.

Since the all datasets do not fit into memory at once, I thought about using a dask.dataframe (ddf). I have already generated the ddf and want to add the dist2coast column now. Here's my pseudo code:

```py
def get_dist2coast(latarr, lonarr, do_interp=True, cfilepath='~/data/dist2coast/dist2coast_1deg.nc'):
""" Calculates distance to coast."""
    #
    # access global/common dist2coast_1deg.nc file
    # e.g.:
    #
    # ds = xr.open_dataset('~/data/dist2coast/dist2coast_1deg_merged.nc')
    # return d2c_vec based on lat+lon values

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: df.assign(dist2coast=get_dist2coast(df.lat, df.lon, do_interp=False)))
```

This piece of code takes about 20s. If I work on a in-memory pandas-dataframe, it takes about 7s.

My first guess is that the bad performance comes from some locking behaviour between the individual threads from which get_dist2coast are being called. dist2coast_1deg_merged.nc comprises distance-to-coast values on a lat/lon grid.

For doing this, I do not really rely on the dask performance optimisation. But certainly I will benefit from it in later processing steps.

What do you think? Is there a way to get around this locking behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

> This piece of code takes about 20s. If I work on a in-memory pandas-dataframe, it takes about 7s.

If you can make Pandas work for you then that is almost always a better choice.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#start-small

> My first guess is that the bad performance comes from some locking behaviour between the individual threads from which get_dist2coast are being called. dist2coast_1deg_merged.nc comprises distance-to-coast values on a lat/lon grid.

Perhaps.  I recommend profiling your code to see what is slow.  Learning that will probably help to guide you towards good performance.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html